# Shortcut to switch to app

Tags: gnome, shortcuts, window, focus

Is it possible to focus an opened app instance/window using a command?

I'd like to assign a keyboard shortcut as to quickly switch to a specific app.

I want shortcuts for:

- chromium (now it opens a new window with blank tab)
- terminator (now it opens a new window)

It works fine for these (running the default command, eg. `thunderbird`):

- thunderbird
- sublime text 2

I am using gnome-shell @ 12.04 (shouldn't matter)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The wmctrl package offers access and manipulation of application windows and would do what you want. Install this little package first:

```
sudo apt-get install wmctrl
```

Here is the man page for wmctrl:
http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/wmctrl.1.html

When you look at the command line switches, you will see that -a will raise and focus a window. In order to know which window to focus, make sure you have a Chromium window open, and then run

```
wmctrl -l
```

This will give you a list of all open windows and their titles. Chromium will most likely always have "Chromium" in the end of it's window title, so you can use that.

With this information at hand, you can construct your command for the shortcut. Open the Keyboard preferences, go to Shortcuts, click on Custom Shortcuts, click the + sign and enter:

```
Name: Focus Chromium Shortcut
Command: wmctrl -a 'Chromium'
```

I am using Unity and just tried this with Google Chrome, it did the trick. It should work in Gnome-Shell as well.

Pretty cool idea :)

DrTebi

Comment: Thanks a ton. Works as expected. As for the terminal, one can use `username@pc_name`.

Comment: I am glad it worked out. You could, if you wanted to, take it a step further and put the wmctrl command into a script. This script could then do further things, e.g. check if there is a window with that name at all, and if not, start the application. This way you could technically setup all your favorite applications to shortcuts, which will have two functions--either start the app if not started yet, or bring it into focus if it is already started... just as an idea if you feel like playing around a bit more.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I am going to do once I get some time ;) Too bad you can't modify apps' titles. You can't for instance target `Clementine` with `wmctrl` as it always has the title of what's playing.

Comment: This works pretty well, with one limitation being that it doesn't seem to be aware of Unity's workspaces. It does have a concept of Desktops, but these don't seem be the same thing. This means that `wmctrl -a 'Google Chrome.'` takes me to the Chrome window on another workspace simply because it occurs first in the window list. I have yet to work out a way to discriminate between windows on different workspaces.

Comment: Actuall @mreq,  `wmctrl` does support changing the title of a window with the `-N` flag.

Comment: Just realised that renaming a window also gets around the problem of distinguishing between windows. However Chrome restores to the window title to one it generates on events like changing tabs etc. The same problem probably applies in the case of the Clementine situation also.

Comment: @humblecoffee Check https://github.com/mreq/wmctile, a ruby wmctrl wrapper written by me. It supports filtering workspaces.

Answer (score 5):

You can use Ubuntu's <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> to <kbd>9</kbd> to switch to your app. Press the **Super** key for three seconds to see the number for each tray icon.
To prevent the app's the number key from changing, you can lock the icons to the Launcher (right-click icons for menu, then choose lock).

Answer (score 0):

A few years ago, I created a small application called [mcgr](https://github.com/akaihola/musomisia) exactly for this purpose. It originally worked only with the Metacity windows manager, but I later adapted it for Gnome.

Comment: Seems good. I went even further with my own [wmctile](https://github.com/mreq/wmctile).

Comment: @mreq wow, looks great, tiling and focus-or-run in a single package! I've also since migrated to tiling window managers, starting with ion3 and moving on to awesome and on to Xmonad. None have focus-or-run put of the box, but it could be added with scripting using available plug-ins. Now I'm experimenting with Gnome-Shell and shellshape, so I need to find a good focus-or-run solution again. BTW, the doc link is broken on http://mreq.github.io/wmctile/build/

Answer (score 0):

I use the following simple script for this. It raises all Windows with the matching title (or tag). 
Run like this for instance:

`winfocus.sh chrome`

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ "" = "$1" ] ; then
    echo "usage $0 Window title"
    exit 1;
fi

wmctrl -lx | grep -i "$1" |cut -d' '  -f1 | while read id; 
   do wmctrl -i -a $id; 
done
```

I have added some Ubuntu keyboard shortcuts to execute this script, so that <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> raises all Chrome and <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> displayes all terminal windows. Works really nice I think.

[image]